# Child - Parent positioning

Tags: python, scripting

I'm working on a script that will add several child objects to a single parent object. One child each time the script is run. I want each child to be moved over and placed next to the previous child on the x-axis. I'm having trouble positioning the children relative to the parent.

How can I set the exact position of a child object relative to its parent object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as

```
child.location = (x,y,z)
```

Comment: If this does not work, post a stripped-down minimal version of your script so that we can run it and see what goes wrong

Comment: Thanks, Mutant Bob. That solved it. I'm new to this, so bear with me and my silly questions.